# Error in Ajax callback only in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'myUrl/etc'
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    error: function(error) {
      alert('Error');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    timeout: 45000
  });

  function callback(result) {
    // Do what i want
  }
```

People. I am getting an error only in IE8 on a ajax callback , I have no idea what might be or why it is happening.

When i try to run the ajax in all browsers the callback will be called, but in IE the alert error will pop up and the console.log will show:

```
LOG: {
 "readyState": "ok",
 "status": 200,
 "statusText": "success"
}
```

I am also printing the jqXHR, textStatus and errorThrown:

```
jqXHR: parserror;
textStatus: callback was not called;
errorThrown: undefined;
```

Any idea why is giving this "error" only in IE8???

Comment: can you check the value returned by the server

Comment: LOG: {
 "readyState": "ok",
 "status": 200,
 "statusText": "success"
}

Comment: It may be either that you are not receiving a json object. Change the datatype to debug that. Or maybe the object you are sending to server is too big. Try to put some logs on the server side to see if it is reaching correct.